# Употребление личного местоимения

Tags: грамматика

Текст: "Ученик некоторое время не отвечает, дуя изо всех сил на красные, иссечённые острыми краями ладони. Их, и так-то натёртых пешнёй до кровавых мозолей, немилосердно щиплет".
Нет ли ошибки в употреблении местоимения "их" в отношении к слову "ладони"? И "натёртых" тоже. Такое ощущение, что есть корявость во втором предложении. Но в чём она выражается, понять не могу!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет никаких ошибок. Местоимение ИХ употреблено верно. И слово "натёртых" в этом контексте употреблено правильно.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду теперь думать, как упростить фразу, в которую с трудом засунул необходимый для сюжета материал. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ну хоть саднит, а не щиплет... Корявость во всем. Вы "немилосердно" усложняете текст, считая, что так будет "выразительнее", а получается просто натужнее. Да при этом оперируете такими заумными терминами, как "тектоника"... Забудьте о ней, будьте проще.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Искреннее. Когда читаешь собственный текст в триста семьдесят первый раз, уже не понимаешь, что кому-то сложно это будет читать. Нужно, что бы тебя кто-то одёргивал всё время. :) Раньше, этим занимались редакторы и корректоры, а теперь... Остаётся надеяться на помощь грамотных людей в Интернете.

Comment: Это — комментарий,  а не ответ.

Comment: Ответ на этот комментарий вот: " Ученик некоторое время не отвечает. Дует изо всех сил на красные, иссечённые острыми краями ладони. И так-то натёртые пешнёй до кровавых мозолей."           :)

Comment: >> *Такое ощущение, что есть корявость во втором предложении. Но в чём она выражается, понять не могу!*  **Ну хоть саднит, а не щиплет... Корявость во всем. Вы "немилосердно" усложняете текст, считая, что так будет "выразительнее", а получается просто натужнее.** Не является?